# NSUserDefaults UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am a novice programmer. Because i'm a newby at Stackoverflow I cannot comment someones anwser yet. I got a question about this post : [How to use NSUserDefaults to save data from ViewController and retrieve it to TableViewController when app reruns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520859/how-to-use-nsuserdefaults-to-save-data-from-viewcontroller-and-retrieve-it-to-ta/)

I try to solve the problem and I read many topics on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the solution. I have the same code as [Rhenzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3511918/rhenzzz) and I implemented the solution explained by [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325271/jay).

I have an error in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method at the line `NSString *itemWish = itemDictionary[@"itemWish"];`.

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WishListItem objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9dc4d80'
```

My full method is :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"wishlistCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *itemDictionary = self.wishlistItem[indexPath.row];
    NSString *itemWish = itemDictionary[@"itemWish"];
    cell.textLabel.text = itemWish;
    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT** :

I forget to precise that my error occurs when I add a new item. The tableview displays datas when I launch the App. But when I add data on my ViewController and then save & go back to the Tableview by clicking on my Done button, I have the error describe above.

So I put some NSLog in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` : `NSLog(@"Display the dictionary:%@",itemDictionary );` and `NSLog(@"Display the item:%@",itemWish );`. Everything is right.

So my problem comes certainly from the IBAction :

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {
    AddItemViewController *source = [unwindSegue sourceViewController];
    WishlistItem *item = source.wishItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.wishlistItem addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

If I delete the `[self.tableView reloadData];` the error disappears but obviously my Tableview is not auto-updated.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is `self.wishlistItem` and array of `NSDictionaries`?

Comment: While SO is a great resource is is not a replacement for reading and studying books on programming and the "C" and Objective-C language (which may be reference material on the web instead of paper).

Answer (score 0):

Given the error, it is clear that `self.wishlistItem` is an array of `WishListItem` objects and not an array of dictionaries. You should change these two lines:

```
NSDictionary *itemDictionary = self.wishlistItem[indexPath.row];
NSString *itemWish = itemDictionary[@"itemWish"];
```

to:

```
WishListItem *wishListItem = self.wishlistItem[indexPath.row];
NSString *itemWish = wishListItem.somePropertyGivingTheDesiredValue;
```

where obviously you need to use the appropriate property on `wishListItem` to get the value you want from it.